# Node auto reload code on https

Tags: node.js, https

I'm looking for a tool which can auto reload my node.js code but also can run on https for local development.

Both forever and nodemon can reload my code but can't run on https.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a self-signed certificate, run the following in your shell:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
rm csr.pem
```

This should leave you with two files, cert.pem (the certificate) and key.pem (the private key). This is all you need for a SSL connection. So now you set up a quick hello world example (the biggest difference between https and http is the options parameter):

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

var a = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

> NODE PRO TIP: Note fs.readFileSync - unlike fs.readFile,
>   fs.readFileSync will block the entire process until it completes. In
>   situations like this - loading vital configuration data - the sync
>   functions are okay. In a busy server, however, using a synchronous
>   function during a request will force the server to deal with the
>   requests one by one!

Reference : https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/